# Is there any way to find the default styling for input text field glow?

Tags: css

You know that sexy glow that surrounds an input field whenever it has focus?

Without going into too much detail, I need to recreate that effect outside of an input field, but I can't seem to find the stylesheet that dictates such an effect anywhere.

(I know how to do it, using the outline property and so on. I'm just wondering if there's a way I can find the EXACT values used by default for input text fields.)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? If you're talking about the text glow, it's that glow that pops up every time you focus on an input field...
Like, right now, for example: [link](http://i.imgur.com/enox5.png)

Comment: As John said, there is no stylesheet. Trial and error with outline, borders and color.

Comment: Sorry for lateness, but hey, you guys were wrong. Even though there's no stylesheet, there definitely are css rules for it, and you can get them by seeing @o.v. answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

chrome has the outline style for inputs as default.  i have to disable that rule for many projects.

use the chrome developer tool to see the browser style rules.

see how to do this here:

[chrome developer tool info](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles)

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to do this via CSS. Have a look at [Twitter Bootstrap Forms](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) and how they do it. Click inside any input field.

See a simple working example here: http://jsbin.com/esidas/2/edit#html,live

It's done using CSS3 properties for `box-shadow` and `transition`

```
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
          border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
       -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
          transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
  /* IE6-9 */

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best cross-browser/cross-platform I know of is [formalize](http://formalize.me/).

If you're trying to figure out how a particular rendering works (i.e. on Safari Mac), you'd be looking for *user agent css*. On modern browsers the entire rendering lifecycle is fully parametrized, heavily relying on vendor-specific prefixes and can be made visible with the inspection tools, e.g. on [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR1Bn.jpg) or FF+Firebug:

[image: FF+Firebug Win]

Answer (score 0):

That's your *browser* doing it for you automatically. That's why you can't find a stylesheet for it.

Comment: Right. I'm aware of that. I'm just wondering if there's a way to get at the specific values it uses, so I can recreate it elsewhere.

Comment: Check the directory where the executable is found. If there is a default stylesheet it probably will be hiding in there somewhere.

Comment: I'll poke around there, then. Let you know what I find.

Comment: Modern browsers rely on user-agent css for rendering - "automatically" doesn't mean "you can't find a stylesheet for it"

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an effect of the browser and not from a style, you'll need to do it manually. In saying that, keep in mind that each browser does it differently (and I think it depends on the client OS as well). So you'll really only be able to match it if you know the client environment beforehand (possible in a closed network).

Answer (score 0):

You know  it is added by the web browser and it depend on the browser and the OS you are using , therefor we can't show you the exact codes. How to find the exact styling may not be difficult, try the 'inspect element' option on an input field, it may show the 'computed styles' by the browser. Else if you can say which browser you use on what OS exactly , we can help you.